# How to refactor duplication out of closures that are an argument to a method call in Groovy?

Tags: grails, groovy, closures

Consider this real world example, which is code written to make 'GET' and 'POST' calls to the same REST service endpoint via the Rest Client Builder (Grails plugin).  I dislike the duplication in that the header and content type setup is identical, but am not sure how to refactor the common pieces out given that they are calling methods on the closure that is being passed to the get() or post() method call.  Please provide a concrete example of a good refactoring out of the duplication in your answer.

```
   private def doGetCall(String endpoint, def config) {
       def response = new RestBuilder().get(config.baseURI+endpoint) {
           contentType("application/json")
           header("Authorization", "ApiKey " + config.base64EncodedApiKey)
           header("ClientId", config.clientId)
       }

       handleResponse(response, config, endpoint);
       return response;
   }

   private def doPostCall(String endpoint, def payload, def config) {
       def response = new RestBuilder().post(config.baseURI+endpoint) {
           contentType("application/json")
           header("Authorization", "ApiKey " + config.base64EncodedApiKey)
           header("ClientId", config.clientId)
           json(payload)
       }

       handleResponse(response, config, endpoint, payload)
       return response;
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy 1.8 added Closure composition, so if you're using a version of Grails which uses Groovy 1.8 or greater:

```
private def doGetCall(String endpoint, def config) {
    def response = new RestBuilder().get(config.baseURI+endpoint, composeRequest(config))

    handleResponse(response, config, endpoint);
    return response;
}

private def doPostCall(String endpoint, def payload, def config) {
    def response = new RestBuilder().post(config.baseURI+endpoint, composeRequest(config, { json(payload) }))

    handleResponse(response, config, endpoint, payload)
    return response;
}

private def composeRequest(def config, Closure clos = null) {
    def request = {
        contentType("application/json")
        header("Authorization", "ApiKey " + config.base64EncodedApiKey)
        header("ClientId", config.clientId)
    }
    if (clos != null) {
        request = request << clos
    }
    request
}
```

Comment: Good answer.  Worked great except I had to replace the line `request << clos' with 'request = request << clos' (I edited the answer)

Answer (score 2):

Will this suffice?

```
class RestTestService {
    def rest

    def methodMissing(String name, args) {
        if( !( name in ['get', 'post'] ) ) { // can add PUT & DELETE in future
            // throw missing method exception for method names other than above
            throw new MissingMethodException(
               "Http Method $name does not exist or not yet implemented.") 
        }

        def (endpoint, config, payload) = args?.toList()

        def response = rest."$name"(config.baseURI + endpoint) {
            contentType( "application/json" )
            header("Authorization", "ApiKey " + config.base64EncodedApiKey )
            header( "ClientId", config.clientId )
            if ( name == 'post' && payload ) {
                json( payload )
            }
        }

        handleResponse(response, config, endpoint)

        return response
    }

    private void handleResponse(def response, def config, def endpoint) { ... }

    public def doGetCall(String endpoint, def config) {
        get( endpoint, config )
    }

    public def doPostCall(String endpoint, def payload, def config) {
        post( endpoint, config, payload )
    }
}

//resources.groovy
beans = {
    rest(grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder)
}
```

Above makes use of `methodMissing` in order to decide which http method to call during runtime.
Also note, instead of creating `RestBuilder` for each http call, I suggest to use it as a bean as shown above in `resources.groovy` and inject it to the class when it is used. If it were a grails artifact (controller, service) then it will be autowired otherwise bean `rest` has to be wired appropriately.
You might abstract by using `doGetCall` and `doPostCall` or totally remove them if required.

Comment: Thanks, clever solution, although I prefer @schmolli's answer as I find it more readable at a glance not having to figure out why methodMissing is being used.

Comment: Fair enough, but you still have to repeat lot of code in both the methods in that solution. Those three lines in both get and post methods are repeated anyways. Back to square one with only difference of little less lines of code. You still have repeated lines of code. Here is how [methodMissing works](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+methodMissing+and+propertyMissing). I still agree with closure coercion and they are effective but here feature like methodMissing in Groovy makes it groovier and DRYier. :) All the best.

Comment: Actually [this is the latest documentation about methodMissing](http://groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/documentation/#_methodmissing). @Pete