# Cleaner way use multiple options with RestBuilder while calling a service

Tags: rest, grails

I have the following code which, I'd like to write in a way that is easy to manage and easy to understand.

```
RestBuilder rest = new RestBuilder()

if (someoption()) {
  rest = rest.post(someurl) {
   contentType: application/json
   json {
     payload1: somepayload
     payload2: somepayload1
   }
  }
}
else {
  rest = rest.post(someurl) {
   contentType: application/json
   json {
     payload4: somepayload4
   }
  }
}
```

The only thing different in the if/else is the json payload. The above just shows one if/else, however, in my actual code I have multiple.

Is there an easy way to manage this? I tried puttind conditional statements in JSON closure but it didn't work

Comment: This seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24792649/how-to-refactor-duplication-out-of-closures-that-are-an-argument-to-a-method-cal

Answer (score 2):

Here's a generalized rest call method that you could use:

```
RestResponse rest(String method, String url, Closure jsonData = null) {
   RestBuilder rest = new RestBuilder()
   rest."$method"(url) {
      contentType: "application/json"
      if (jsonData) {
         json {
            jsonData.delegate = delegate
            jsonData()
         }
      }
   }
}
```

and you could call it with

```
RestResponse response
if (someoption()) {
   response = rest('post', someurl) {
      payload1: somepayload
      payload2: somepayload1
   }
}
else {
   response = rest('post', someurl) {
      payload4: somepayload4
   }
}
```

or

```
def json
if (someoption()) {
   json = {
      payload1: somepayload
      payload2: somepayload1
   }
}
else {
   json = {
      payload4: somepayload4
   }
}

RestResponse response = rest('post', someurl, json)
```

Comment: That generalized method is great. Won't we need this line at the beginning of that method though? `RestBuilder rest = new RestBuilder()`

Comment: also, there is a NPE while assigning data to `json` variable in the last example. `Cannot invoke method call() on null object`. I tried converting `def json` to `def json = new JSON()` but that did not help

Comment: On second look everything works as expected. I was missing the `=` sign. If i do `json {payload1: somepayload}` then I get a NPE, however, if I do `json = {payload1: somepayload}` then everything works fine. Can you please explain the difference.

Comment: You need the `=` because you're setting a value of a local variable. The other syntax works when declaring the closure inline because it's a DSL that has support for that syntax. But it only works inside a RestBuilder post/get/put/etc. call.